# MS Project autoschedule - full days of work are bleeding into next day

Tags: tasks, ms-project-2013, task-management

I'm scheduling weeks of work in Microsoft Project (2013) wherein each task will normally take a full day of work/duration for a crew. I'm scheduling them for 10-hour days and the duration of the work is 10 hours, and I've adjusted the default calendar as such. For the most part, only one task may be accomplished in a day (due to safety, set-up and break-down time) and for my planning purposes I won't be tracking if they finish tasks early.

If all my tasks are 10h like this I haven't seen any issues, however I do have some tasks that will require more time (12 hours for instance) and some that will take less time (4h) and I've set up the predecessors to take advantage of those oddities (do 10 hours of Task A and pick it up next morning, then finish Task B). However this throws everything downstream off by X-hours and I end up with partial-tasks running over the weekend to the following workday (which as I mentioned isn't possible due to the nature of the work). I tried using "1ed" for my 10h tasks, however then my budget calculations will be for 24h of work.

How can I set up these tasks such that they "round up" to the nearest full day?

Comment: It seems that you will need to define a quasi deadline (manually) for last work of week, and let the work effort shrink.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Task Type to "Fixed Work", then manually adjust the duration of the task so it ends at the end of the day. The "Fixed Work" setting will ensure the amount of work is not recalculated when you lengthen the duration of the task.

Unfortunately there is no way of doing this automatically.